# How to prove that a series is equal to a recursive algorithm

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, recursive-algorithms

I have the following sequence:
$$
y_n = \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{x+5}\,dx, n = 0,1,\dots
$$

Now I have the following recursive algorithm:

$$
y_0 = \log{6} - \log{5}
$$
$$
y_n = \frac{1}{n} - 5y_{n-1}, n = 1,...
$$

I tried to prove that this algorithm is equal to the sequence.
I thought I would have to do complete induction:

Induction start:
$$
y_n = 1 - 5\log6 + 5\log5 = \left.(x- 5\log(x+5))\right|_0^1 = \int_0^1 \frac{x}{x+5}\,dx
$$

Induction step $(n \longrightarrow n+1)$:
$$
\frac{1}{n+1} - 5 y_n = \frac{1}{n+1} -5\left(\frac{1}{n}-5y_{n-1}\right)= \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{5}{n} + 25 y_{n-1} = -5\left(\frac{1}{-5(n+1)}+\frac{1}{n}-5y_{n-1}\right) = \frac{1}{n+1} -5\left(\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{x+5}\,dx\right) = ...?
$$

Can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really a problem for induction; you're not trying to prove that the statement for $n$ implies it for $n+1$.  Rather, you can prove it essentially as a _function_ of $n$, for all $n$ at once.  For doing the problem that way, you're going 'the wrong direction'; rather than trying to prove that the series has the integral representation, it's much easier to prove that the sequence of integrals satisfies the recurrence relation for $y_n$.  This is what AstroSharp's answer does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y_n=\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-1}(x+5-5)}{x+5}dx=\int_0^1x^{n-1}\left[\frac{x+5}{x+5}-\frac{5}{x+5}\right]=$$ $$=\int_0^1x^{n-1}dx-5\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-1}}{x+5}dx=\frac{1}{n}-5y_{n-1}$$

Comment: i dont understand the first step $$y_n=\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-1}(x+5-5)}{x+5}dx=\int_0^1x^{n-1}dx-5\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-1}}{x+5}dx$$

Comment: @user36371 I added an extra step for you. Check it out. Maybe a bit more clear ?

Comment: thanks, but i don't get it.

Comment: @user36371 http://bit.ly/10cij68

Comment: ok i got it :D how bad, thank you very much

Comment: @user36371 Now, if you want to practice and convince yourself that you really understand the idea, try to get a recursive formula for $\int_0^1\frac{x^n}{(x+5)^2}dx$, if you do it, I guaranty you will feel great about it!

Comment: damn i tried, but failed :D i just get $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n}+x^{n-1}}{(x+5)^2} - y_{n-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

In the first case prove $$y_n+5y_{n-1}=\frac1n\text{ for } n>0$$ and $$y_0=\ln\frac65$$