# Find another recursive algorithm that is equal to a series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, recursive-algorithms

I have the following sequence:
$$
y_n = \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{x+5}\,dx, n = 0,1,\dots
$$

Now I have the following recursive algorithm which is equal to the sequence:

$$
y_0 = \log{6} - \log{5}
$$
$$
y_n = \frac{1}{n} - 5y_{n-1}, n = 1,...
$$

I have to find another recursive algorithm equal to the sequence. I got the tip to write the recursion backwards e.g start with $y_9 \approx 0$

I don't get it, can you help me, thanks.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537027/how-to-prove-that-a-series-is-equal-to-a-recursive-algorithm

Comment: For what it is worth, this is a sequence, not a series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the equation $y_n = 1/n - 5 y_{n-1}$.  But instead of using this to calculate $y_n$ from $y_{n-1}$, you can use it to calculate $y_{n-1}$ from $y_n$.  As a starting point take $y_N \approx 0$ where $N$ is fairly large.
The fact that this "backwards" recursion is very stable (error is divided by $5$ at each step) means that even if the approximation for $y_N$ is not very good, you will get very good approximations after a few steps.